# racket - figure with random digits

Tags: random, racket

I am trying to write recursive function that will generate figure with n random digits. To generate a numbers I want to use `(random 10)`. I want function to decrease n until it reachs 0.

```
(define (generate-number n)
  (if (= n 0) 0
       (generate-number (- n 1))))
```

Can someone please help me where to place `(random 10)` and make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Collecting n random numbers (till 10) in a list:**

```
(define (random-list n)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons (random 10)
            (random-list (sub1 n)))))

(random-list 10)
```

**or displaying them:**

```
(define (display-n-random n)
  (cond
    [(= n 0) (void)]
    [else    (displayln (random 10))
             (display-n-random (sub1 n))]))

(display-n-random 10)
```

---

This is how you'd generate a number with n random digits using `(random 10)`:

```
(define (generate-number n)
  (cond [(= n 1) (random 10)]
        [else (+ (random 10)
                 (* 10 (generate-number (sub1 n))))]))

(generate-number 10)
```

Note that the base case is for a single digit number since 0 digit numbers do not exit.

Comment: My assignemt was to write a procedure that accepts n number and generates random figure of n digits. To do so, generate numbers one by one.
So i have supposed that procedure will generate numbers until it reachs the limit condition. Thank you for your time.